# My 2 buttons are in left corner, don´t know why?

Tags: android, android-button, android-relativelayout

I don´t know why my two buttons are in the left corner?
They should be like the 3rd one! I haven´t found any mistake. It would be nice if someone knows what is wrong. Thank you!

Here you can see how it looks acctualy
[image]

Code:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    TextView tvDate = new TextView(this);
    tvDate.setText("Date");
    tvDate.setId(R.id.tvDate);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    tvDate.setLayoutParams(p1);
    p1.setMargins(0,30,0,0);

    tvDate.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    tvDate.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25);
    relativeLayout.addView(tvDate);

    Button btNew = new Button(this);
    btNew.setId(R.id.btNew);
    btNew.setText(R.string.btNew);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    lp.setMargins(0,120,0,0);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.tvDate);
    btNew.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

relativeLayout.addView(btNew);

```
    Button btShowTests = new Button(this);
    btShowTests.setId(R.id.btShowTests);
    btNew.setText(R.string.btShowTests);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    p2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    p2.setMargins(0,210,0,0);
    p2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.btNew);
    btNew.setLayoutParams(p2);

    relativeLayout.addView(btShowTests);

    Button btCheckTest = new Button(this);
    btNew.setText(R.string.btShowTests);
    btNew.setId(R.id.btCheckTest);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    p3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    p3.setMargins(0,300,0,0);
    p3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.btShowTests);
    btNew.setLayoutParams(p3);

    relativeLayout.addView(btCheckTest);

    this.setContentView(relativeLayout);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code. The first is the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` you're using for your "Date" `TextView`. You have this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

but you should use `WRAP_CONTENT` for the height instead. If you leave it as `FILL_PARENT`, you won't be able to see *any* of your buttons once you fix the second problem. This is because the `TextView` will fill the entire screen, so anything `BELOW` it will be pushed off-screen.

The second is that your code incorrectly refers to `btNew` in places where it should not. For example:

```
Button btShowTests = new Button(this);
btShowTests.setId(R.id.btShowTests);
btNew.setText(R.string.btShowTests);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
p2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
p2.setMargins(0,210,0,0);
p2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.btNew);
btNew.setLayoutParams(p2);

relativeLayout.addView(btShowTests);
```

In this code you're calling `btNew.setText()` and `btNew.setLayoutParams()`, when you should be calling `btShowTests.setText()` and `btShowTests.setLayoutParams()`. You have the same problem for your third button:

```
Button btCheckTest = new Button(this);
btNew.setText(R.string.btShowTests);
btNew.setId(R.id.btCheckTest);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
p3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
p3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
p3.setMargins(0,300,0,0);
p3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.btShowTests);
btNew.setLayoutParams(p3);

relativeLayout.addView(btCheckTest);
```

All references in this section to `btNew` should be replaced with `btCheckTest`. Once all that's done, your buttons will all appear:

[image]

(Note that the third button re-uses the same string as the second button. You will probably want to change this as well.)